# problem with omp_set_num_threads set to different values in two threads

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, openmp

Using Visual Studio 2017
I have two different threads running, they both use omp, but call omp_set_num_threads with different values.  Note that the machine supports 24 threads.

Thread 1:

```
omp_set_num_threads(20)
#pragma omp parallel for
for(...
```

Thread 2:

```
omp_set_num_threads(18)
#pragma omp parallel
int ith = omp_get_thread_num();
if(ith >= 18)
{
TRACE("ith %d, actual number of threads %d\n",ith,omp_get_num_threads())
```

After a few thousand executions the if statement becomes true, and it prints 18 or 19 for ith, and 20 for number of threads. So during execution of the parallel code in Thread 2, the number of threads has changed from 18 to 20

A solution would be to call omp_set_num_threads always with the same value, but that is undesirable because depending on the type and size of the problem it may be better to use more or less threads

Comment: What is your question? `ith` is undeclared in your second code (and `;`is missing) . How about using a `{` `}` block after `#pragma omp parallel`?

Comment: The structure of your code is unclear. Are you using nested threading (i.e. are your two pieces of code in a another, higher level, parallel region) ? Or are they just completely independent parallel regions (in this case these are not "thread 1" and "thread 2", but "parallel region 1" and "parallel region 2") ?

Comment: It would be best if you provide a [mre] and a clear question.

Comment: If I recall correctly `omp_set_num_threads` is global, this is why for instance MKL comes with its own `mkl_set_num_threads_local` function. This means that setting threads in this way affects both thread1 and thread2 (when they enter their respective OMP regions). A simple solution would be to simply add `num_threads(18)` and `num_threads(20)` to the respective pragmas and set the number of threads that way.

Comment: @Qubit calling `omp_set_num_threads()` before each region is equivalent to specify the `num_threads` clause.